# QT Signal / Slot

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, qtgui, qt-signals

I've got a question about signals and slots. In my app, I want to connect a signal from one object to a `textEdit` in a dialog window. My signal emits a `QString`; if I violate encapsulation (by making the UI public instead of private) and connect the signal directly to the `textEdit` it works. But I feel that it's not the right way. If I make something like the following:

```
connect(m_osgWidget->picker.get(), SIGNAL(setX(QString)), m_addAgentDlg, SLOT(getX(QString)));
```

where:

```
void getX(QString)
{
    this->ui.textEdit(QString);
}
```

It gives me an error that I can't use `QString` in this `this->ui.textEdit(QString);` I need the `QString` from `setX()` signal pasted into the `textEdit` of `m_addAgentDlg`. How this can be done? Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry to say this, but you need to learn basic C++. The proper syntax is this for such things in C++ with Qt:

```
connect(m_osgWidget->picker.get(), SIGNAL(setX(const QString&)), m_addAgentDlg, SLOT(getX(const QString&)));

// Why do you call it getX? Should it be called setText instead?
void getX(const QString& string)
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(string);
}
```

Comment: Well, i still learn so it's not necessary to say. I have tried every possible type of code posted above, including one that you provided. It doesn't work. Thats why i ask it here. I continue get messages that there is no such slot in object.

Comment: @AzraithSherkhan: you have to rerun qmake, but please buy a C++ book. It is necessary to say as these situations are why the authors spent their lives with them.